# how to call API on specific interval with request and response object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to call my express API on every 30 seconds.

API calls function by forwarding response & request object and in that function, as response, renders HTML page. This HTML page should be refresh on every 30 seconds if any data change noticed in database.

**server.js**

```js
app.get('/display/:id', function (req, res) 
{
  setInterval(function(){mapCoords(req,res);},3000);
});
function mapCoords(req, res)
{
  //render html with coords
}
```

Comment: There're several ways, you could use node cron or system.d or forever

Comment: You should see how database trigger  work. And what you want to know is known as long polling(comet)

Comment: I can fetch coordinates from database successfully, after that what i have to is to render this coordinates on leaflet map, after 30 seconds map refresh if coordinates changed in database.